# Android Radio Buttons

Tags: java, android, eclipse

If i have radio buttons with the same text and the same properties in a group , how to find which radio button was selected ? Everywhere are examples with different texts in radio buttons

Comment: Why do you have multiple radio buttons with the same properties? That defeats the purpose. Radio buttons should be used to choose different choices.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `RadioGroup` that determines which Radio Button was clicked, like this:

```
   RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // the radio button selected is checkedId
        }
    });
```

Comment: as far as I understood , I get the ID of the checked button , but how Can I logically understand which one was checked if they have the same parameters

Comment: @SamArmen The names of the buttons shouldn't be the same, since they're different buttons.

Comment: can I get the ID with string ?

Comment: @SamArmen The `checkedId` will correspond to the different Radio Button's `checkedButton` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class RadioButtonExample extends Activity {

            private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
            private RadioButton radioSexButton;  
            private Button btnDisplay;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio_button_example);

                addListenerOnButton();

            }

            public void addListenerOnButton() {

                radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGender);
                btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

                btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                        int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                        // find the radiobutton by returned id
                        radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

                        Toast.makeText(RadioButtonExample.this,
                                radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                });

            }
}
```

Comment: I emphasized that I have the same text for radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

you need to group the radio buttons under a radio button group to determine the button selection. This may help you with an idea:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html